# why the JS function not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to spring mvc and static web resource and trying to rebuild a project, but I have problem if someone can explain to me why the JS function not working?

About the project (Spring MVC web application using the Spring Boot framework. and use the JSP as view for the web application).

app.js

```
function validate() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    if (name == '') {
        alert('Please enter a valid name.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<!-- Static content -->

<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/app.js"></script>
<title>SchoolApp</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Spring Boot - MVC design</h1>
  <hr>

  <div class="form">
    <form action="hello" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Enter Your name</td>
          <td><input id="name" name="name"></td>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is "not working"...?! Any error messages? Why is your backend and pom file relevant for a JavaScript question? Maybe try to break down the problem and include only the relevant parts, as not many people are willing to work through 6+ code blocks first

Comment: @Capricorn, I didn't get any error message,  that's what confuses me, So I'm just trying to know why the JS function not working

Comment: I just moved your code into a jsfiddle and it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/z8gm7uab/4/ Can you double check that the `app.js` file is properly loaded in your index file? (Check developer tools network tab for example)

Comment: JS file loaded properly.

Comment: @Robert the reason to share all the code, because I couldn't find where is the problem or what causes the problem in my code !

Comment: The code should be debugged to identify the precise spot at which the issue occurs. It should then either be rewritten from scratch until the issue reappears or the original code should be largely cut through to remove working pieces which are not directly related to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Validation Plugin solve the issue

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Only alphabetical characters");

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                lettersonly: true,
            }
        }
    });

});
```